# Can twins that develop in separate sacs but share the same placenta be identical?

Tags: human-biology, cell-biology, twins

I have two younger non identical twin sisters. When my mum was pregnant she was told they were both in different sacs when developing but shared the same placenta.

We have done hours of research on the topic, as we have reason to believe they could after all actually be identical.

After all this research we’ve just found a load of fancy names for twins and no information on non identical twins that share the same placenta and are in different sacs.

Another thing that may help is that they are mirror twins.

Comment: Welcome to Biology Stack Exchange! I modified the wording of question a little bit to bring out the actual question about biology.

Answer (score 1):

> they were both in different sacs when developing but shared the same
> placenta

This suggests that they were [monochorionic diamniotic twins](https://radiopaedia.org/articles/monochorionic-diamniotic-twin-pregnancy), which would mean they are monozygotic, i.e. identical.